# .NET MVC: Run a piece of code in many uncompiled .cs-files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently building a web app that will take some info from a database and replace some text in a Word document with that information. Then the document will be saved to a predefined location.

Problem now is that when development began we were talking about 5 documents, but now we are looking at 20+ and documents will probably change over time. My intial thought was to "hardcode" classes for each document. But now that seems like a a really stupid idea.

The signature for the method would probably be something like: `void Generate(string template, string outputFileName);`. How is this done in the best way? Let's say I create an interface `IGenerator` which defines the Generate method and some method to describe the current "plugin". Could I then simply put .cs-files (or dlls) with a single class implementing that interface in some directory and then let the application find all these and let the user choose one?

EDIT: Is there a good way to add/edit/delete these `Document`-classes without having to recompile the entire app or library with all classes? I would like each Document-class to stand for itself. I've read this [article](http://shazwazza.com/post/Developing-a-plugin-framework-in-ASPNET-with-medium-trust.aspx), which might be my best choice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at using a Factory Pattern to produce your document instances and if you need to deal with different document types then think about having an `Document` abstract class that exposes overrideable methods for getting data from and into a document.

You then code to handle the `Document` class and not specific child classes as the rest of your code doesn't care what the document is, only that it is handling one.

You would then need to implement a `Document` sub-class to cope with different document types (Word .doc, .docx; Excel, Text etc.) and generate an instance of the correct class by using a `Document` Factory to which you pass a variable to determine the creation of the correct `Document` sub-class.

If you are to have multiple documents in existance at anyone time then you store instances of them in a `List<Document>`.

**edit**

Well here's my thinking based on what you've stated so far.
You're really only dealing with Office documents and so you can either use an Office SDK, in which case you'll need to load up the appropriate library or if you stick to Open XML format documents, you can produce them yourself.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313118%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for information on Office document formats.

In any case you'll be dealing with say a Word document or an Excel document, but you may have multiple layouts of a Word document.

If you write your document class to accept template information of some sort then you can store this in XML either in your database or within a config file.

If storing within a config file then reference it as a data source from your `web.config` e.g.

```
<appSettings datasource="different.config"/>
```

That way you can make changes to the `appSettings` stored within `different.config` **without** needing to restart your web pages.

Comment: Thank you. I now realize that my other question got a bit hidden in the original post. The problem that still exists is that these documents can change/more can be added and so on, so I'm also asking for a good way to change/edit/add the new `Document` classes without having to recompile more than I actually need. Original post updated with more info as well.

Comment: I'm still a little unsure about the documents that you're dealing with. When you say that "these documents can change/more can be added" do you mean the type of document? How do they differ - layout, means of display, database fields? They're all Word docs aren't they?

Comment: Word and Excel documents. These can be letters, PM, projects plan, description etc etc. From the beginning there would be one PM, one plan and so on. Now it seems like they would be able to go "here I want to be able to generate another type of (Word-)document". So I have to build a class for each type (PM, letter, etc) that fetches all the info from the DB and puts it into the document. The problem now is that a week after I'm "done" they might say "we want a new type of doc". Therefore I'm looking for some kind of nice plugin-platform so that I only have to upload one file and not rebuild.

Comment: Will your Word/Excel documents have to be backward compatible or would use of Open XML format e.g. docx be sufficient?

Comment: No Open XML is fine. The Word/Excel part is complete, I have code for the "replacing/generating" part. So my problem now is that I want to be able anytime to create a new "type" of document (say ProjectOverview) and in some easy way integrate this new document with the existing web application. Preferably by uploading a .cs (or a DLL) file to some directory on the server, and then the application finds it, the user can in UI register in and bind it to a new type of document.